# Is there any command that can completely delete a package?

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any command that can completely delete a package, which is built from sources in a catkin workspace, on Ubuntu?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226421/is-there-any-command-that-can-completely-delete-a-package?/) by [percy_liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25923/percy_liu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-12**:
Please clarify: a package installed on Ubuntu/Debian using `apt-get`, a package built from sources in a catkin workspace, something else ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If by completely deleting you mean "removing a repo and not making it reappear after `wstool update`" I don't think so. We've been using a small script that first removes a repo from a workspace and then deletes the folder afterwards: [rm_from_workspace.sh](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_scripts/blob/master/scripts/rm_from_workspace.sh) (It's pretty simple, there might be nicer solutions out there).

If you really just want to get rid of a package you just have to remove the corresponding folder and that's it.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1